# How can I took nestable element titles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I took all id's and childrens JSON encoded but I need titles of it also when I took JSON format how can I do that?

```
$ (document).ready (function() {
     let a = 0;
     let updateOutput = function (e) {
     a+;
     let list = e.length? E: $ (e.target),
     output = list.data ('output');
     if (window.JSON) {
     output.val (window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize')));
     if (a>2) {
     $.post ("/admin/Menus/update", {"menu_title":list[0].id,"menus":window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))}, (response)=>{
     responseAlert (response.status, response.reply);
     },"JSON");
     }
     } else {
     output.val ('JSON browser support required for this demo.');
     }
     };
     $ ('#header-menu').nestable ({
     group: 1
     }).on ('change', updateOutput);
     $ ('#footer-menu').nestable ({
     group: 1
     }).on ('change', updateOutput);
     updateOutput ($ ('#header-menu').data ('output', $ ('#nestable-output');
     updateOutput ($ ('#footer-menu').data ('output', $ ('#nestable2-output');
     $ ('#nestable-menu').on ('click', function (e) {
     let target = $ (e.target),
     action = target.data ('action');
     if (action === 'expand-all') {
     $ ('.dd').nestable ('expandAll');
     }
     if (action === 'collapse-all') {
     $ ('.dd').nestable ('collapseAll');
     }
     });
     $ ('#nestable-menu').nestable();
    });
```

I need a json output like {"id":5, "title":"Home"} but my output is {"id":5}

`<li class="dd-item" data-id="3">
    <div class="dd-handle"> C# </div>
</li>`

Comment: please add the data, you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have the following

```
$.post ("/admin/Menus/update", {"menu_title":list[0].id,"menus":window.JSON.stringify(list.nestable('serialize'))}, (response)=>{
     responseAlert (response.status, response.reply);
```

try to do the same but use : list[0].title

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, thank you by the way.

`<li class="dd-item" data-title="Item 8" data-id="<?=$menu->id?>">
    <div class="dd-handle"> Anasayfa </div>
</li>`